# Distance between colorings

Tags: graph-theory, coloring, ramsey-theory

Say I have a graph $G$ which has edges colored with colors red and blue. Let's call this coloring $C$. Is there a way I can say that one coloring is closer to $C$ compared to another? Perhaps saying it is easier to reach from one coloring of a graph to $C$ compared to another coloring of a graph.

For example, if let's call it $A$ if all edges are colored red, $B$ if all the edges are colored blue, and $C$ is the coloring which has all edges blue except one, which is red. This $C$ is obviously closer to $B$ than $A$ in some sense.

Can I quantify it?

Comment: Why not use a Kronecker delta type metric where the metric $d$ for a graph $G$ and edge $E$ for two colorings $A,B$ are such that $d_E(A,B) = 1$ only if the colors don't match? And $d(A,B) = \sum_E d_E(A,B)$?